# Meteor: Integration with Mongoose?

Tags: orm, meteor, mongoose

I noticed you guys are planning on adding more ORM features into your platform, but in the meantime, is there an easy way to extend your Collections with Mongoose Collections?

Comment: Is this something you wanted serverside only?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to add:

```
npm install mongoose
```

To "admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh"

You can then create a new package and require mongoose, within that you can assign the method to: Meteor.mongoose too and connect to the MONGO_URL (This is Meteors database) for this command. Take a look round the other packages if you need some help.

I did the sample work in this branch:
https://github.com/jonathanKingston/meteor/tree/mongoose

This is 100% untested as I'm on a windows machine at the moment but it should open up:
Meteor.mongoose and just normal mongoose for the standard use as explained here but already connected:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose#readme

Answer (score 0):

an issue with mongoose is that it won't work on the client.  So you'll lose much of the benefit of using Meteor.

Take a look at [Collections2](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2) it offers validation and structure.

Good luck!